# Is there a way to do css inside an html body?

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I'm trying to change the background color multiple times within one page. Is there a way to put CSS in an HTML body?

Comment: That's how css works.  What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: Sure. You can have it in-line as `type` attribute or inside `HEAD` as `<style>` block .

Answer (score 5):

There are two primary ways to do this:

## 1. Inline (Styles)

`<div style="background-color: blue;"></div>`

## 2. In-Page Block (Styles)

These are typically defined in the `<head>` section of the page.

```
<style>
.bg-blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
</style>
```

If you are going to write your styles within a single page, I strongly advise going with "Option #2: In-Page Block" since it allows for reusability and is easier to maintain.

Does that help to answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<style></style>` tags and put styling inside them, too. Best put into the `<head>` section.

```
<style>
body p {
   font-size: 18px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "Can I write inline css within the html body" then yes, you can! (See below). But having a separate CSS stylesheet is generally considered the better option.

```
<div id="myDiv" style="background-color:red;">
<!-- content -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `style="add your attribute here"` to an element  and then separate attributes by adding `;` between attributes;

```html
<body>

<h1 style="color:blue;margin-left:30px;">This is a heading.</h1>
<p style="color:red;margin-left:30px;">This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default css is always inside an html body. One way is to create custom styling classes with simple names, and insert the class name inside the li or p tag around your text. If it is the background color of certain entries that you want to change, do so on an entry-by-entry basis.
.p (or .li, or p style="background-color:#c0c0c0;")
{
background-color:#c0c0c0; would give you a silver-gray BG color
}
This can be put into a single line with the open and closing style tags.
You will need to do this for each line or paragraph that has an original or unique BG color. The color chosen stays in effect until you change it.